# Не работает INSERT INTO $add_comment = mysqli_query($connection," INSERT INTO comments (name, text) VALUES

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

```
<div class="container_koment">
<h1 id="zagcoment">Коментарий</h1>
<p id="autor_comment"><?php echo $comment['autor_comment'] ?></p>
<p id="text_comment"><?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($comment['text']),0,200,'utf-8')?></p>
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
<br>
<div id="yakor" class="container4">
<?php
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'send')) {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $text = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'text');
    if (!$name or !$text) {
     echo '<h1 id="error_comment">Вы не ввели все данные!!!</h1>';
    } else {
      $add_comment = mysqli_query($connection," INSERT INTO comments (name, text) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$text."') ");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). Изучать до полного понимания.

Comment: Думаю что у вас проблемы не в скрипте а в понимании web в целом.

Comment: я понял,что есть Ключевые слова и зарезервированные слова.О зарезервированные слова с кавычками,а незарезервированные без кавычек

Comment: Но что это даёт

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score -1):

Во первых, что это?

```
<?php
} 
?>
```

Страница уже сломалась.
Во-вторых, хотя это не критично, можно писать так:

```
"INSERT INTO comments (name, text) VALUES ('$name', '$text')"
```

Comment: во-первых это закрывающая скобка предыдущего блока. Во-вторых, это не ответ, а комментарий.

Comment: }от другого блока

Comment: так сделайте, чтобы в комментариях можно было читабельный код вставлять